# Identifying within-individual treatment effect with RDD-style models

Tags: panel-data, treatment-effect, regression-discontinuity

I have panel data with various products as individuals, observed over some period of time, and the plausibly exogenous (in this case) entry of competing products as "treatment". Treatment timing differs across individuals, and can be considered exogenous to the outcome of interest: short-term sales dynamics.

My plan to measure the "treatment effect" on sales is to borrow from regression discontinuity design. I intend to replace the time variable by a "distance-to-treatment" variable (say `distance`), then pool products by `distance`, fit some local or polynomial regression of sales on `distance`, include the possibility for a discontinuity at `distance=0` and see if this discontinuity is significant.

This methodology obviously differs from RDD in that there's no control group; pre-treatment products are their own controls for post-treatment effect. In panel language, I guess we could say that the treatment is "within" individuals. In some way this is akin to structural breaks in time series, but the data is not suited to time-series analysis. The time dimension is too short.

Anyway, I would appreciate feedback on whether this is an appropriate methodology, as well as references if there are any. I don't even know if there's a name for such an approach.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: At first blush, this does not seem like a good strategy because it emphasizes data right around competing product introduction. Since behavioral and market adjustments often take time, you probably care more about about the long-run elasticity of substitution rather than what happens right around introduction cutoff.

Comment: That it indeed an issue, however if I have some reasons to suspect rapid demand shifts, would this strategy by relevant? As in, not foolproof but still informative and not fallacious nor misleading.

Comment: It entry is truly exogenous, should be OK. But then I don't see what RDD gets you over a more traditional regression approach.